# Why does $\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \cot \psi$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

In the discussion of linear fractional equations in Birkhoff and Rota's *Ordinary Differential Equations*, the authors assert that if we convert a DE of the form $y' = F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ to polar coordinates, then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \cot \psi,
\end{align}
where $\psi = \gamma - \theta$, with $\gamma$ being the tangent direction and $\theta$ the radial direction.  I'm afraid this has me entirely buffaloed -- why on earth is this true?  I have neither an analytic nor geometric intuition as to how this could possibly be.  I'm sure there's some elementaryish fact about $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ which makes the answer obvious, but I have no clue what said fact is.

I do note that 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{d\theta} &= r\cos\theta + \frac{dr}{d\theta}\sin\theta\Rightarrow\\
\frac{dr}{d\theta} & = \frac{dy}{d\theta}\csc\theta - r\cot\theta\Rightarrow\\
\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta} & = \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{d\theta} - \cot\theta, 
\end{align}
but this is as close as I can come to getting a cotangent anywhere near the expression (and, of course, $\theta \neq \psi$ in general).

What gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prove of the relationship  $\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \cot (\gamma -\theta )$ is shown below :

[image]

On the figure, the relationship is easy to intuitively understand in the triangle PQT where PQ$=dr$ , QT$=r d\theta$ and angle$=(\gamma-\theta)$, of course infinitely magnified.

[image]