# What is $\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates

Suppose we have an equation of a polar curve with usual notation $r=f(\theta).$
I am curious about the geometric meaning of $$\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}=f'(\theta).$$ Also I would like to know the relations between $f'(\theta)$ and tangent at $(r, \theta).$
Thank you.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250102/why-does-frac1r-fracdrd-theta-cot-psi?rq=1

Comment: I know this is an old question but I found this geometric interpretation on Quora: https://qr.ae/prj86O which seems reasonable. Is it safe to say that dr/dθ at a particular point on a curve is the length of the polar subnormal at that point? I drew out the polar graph for r=sinθ and drew the polar subnormals at θ=π/3, π/4, π/6 (cont.)

Comment: The length of the subnormal decreases as the angel increases, as expected. but for angles like π/2, the tangent and the perpendicular drawn at the origin are parallel. So the subnormal is impossible to draw. Yet dr/dθ=0 for r=sinθ at θ=π/2. Is there a better way to interpret dr/dθ geometrically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just the rate of change of the radius with angle. For instance, if you describe a circle, you would expect this derivative to be zero, since the radius does not change with angle, and this is seen by $f(\theta) = R \Longrightarrow f'(\theta)=0$.

The tangent to the curve can be calculated as follows. The curve is given by:
$$(x,y)= (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)=f(\theta)\cdot(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$$
The slope of the tangent is defined by $m= dy/dx$, so:
$$m=\frac{dy}{dx} = \left. \frac{dy}{d\theta}\middle/\frac{dx}{d\theta}\right.=
\frac{f'(\theta)\sin\theta+f(\theta)\cos\theta}{f'(\theta)\cos\theta-f(\theta)\sin\theta}$$

Answer (score 5):

A picture speaks louder than words:
[image]

---

**EDIT** assume that $\Delta x$ and $\Delta \theta$ are very close to $0$.
In addition, this picture intuitively explains why $\tan \gamma=\frac{r}{r'(\theta)}$ in @Narasimham's answer. (Can you see how?)

Answer (score 4):

If angle made by radial line to polar curve is $\gamma$ at any point, then

$$ \tan \gamma = \dfrac {r}{f^{'}(\theta)} $$

which can be regarded as a local "slope" for tangent to polar curve with respect to radial lines. For a radial it is zero and for circles centered at origin, $ \pi/2.$

EDIT1:

They are differential trig.relations. Consider the small differential triangle.

Opposite side is $r d\theta,$ adjacent side is $ dr,$ hypotenuse is $ ds.$ So,

$ \tan\gamma =\dfrac{rdθ}{dr} =\dfrac{r}{r'}; \sin \gamma =\dfrac{r}{s'};\cos \gamma =\dfrac{r'}{s'};\; $

Please note them down as they are very useful in setting up ODEs.

Comment: Why is this? Can you direct me to proof?

Comment: It is differential trig. Consider  the small differential triangle. Opposite side is $ r d\theta$ adjacent side is $dr$ .So  $ \tan \gamma = ( r d \theta)/dr $  $= \dfrac {r}{r^{'}}$

Comment: Edited this in answer also.