# Is there a name for $\frac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}$?

Tags: geometry, vectors, terminology, circles

I know the derivative of angle with respect to time, $\vec{\omega}=\frac{d\theta}{dt}$, is angular velocity.

Is there an analogous name for the derivative of position with respect to angle, $\frac{d\vec{r}}{d\theta}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\dfrac{dr}{d\theta}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316753/what-is-dfracdrd-theta)

Comment: @Ak19 No, fraid not.

Comment: I wouldn't hold out too much hope about it having a well-known, specific name. It is often easier to refer to terms like this symbolically in writing or by speaking out their constituent letters in speech.

Comment: For many paths, $\vec{r}$ is not a function of $\theta$. Only certain special polar graphs, basically. So there might not be enough opportunity for this to be worth naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Author answer*

Comments suggest the answer is 'no'.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1358356)

Comment: @NoelLundström This answer is by me, the author, in order to close the question.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! My bad, I'll check for that in the future!