# Prove that $ \tan \beta = r\frac{d \theta}{dr} $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading from [*Ordinary Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com.gh/books/about/Ordinary_Differential_Equations.html?id=iU4zDAAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) **(Lesson 13 Example 13.3 page 110)** and came across this question:

> Find the family of curves such that the angle from a tangent to a
>   normal at any point of a curve of the family is bisected by the radius
>   vectors at that point. (In problems involving radius vectors, it is
>   usually preferable to use polar coordinates.)

And these are some steps for the solution(**The solution was having a diagram**):
[image]

> Let $P(r,\theta)$ be the polar coordinates of a point on the angle
>   measured from the radius vector r counterclockwise to the tangent line
>   at $P$. Then by a theorem in the calculus 
>   $$ \tan \beta = r\frac{d\theta}{dr}  $$

---

My question is how did they get $ \tan \beta = r\frac{d\theta}{dr} $ and also what theorem in calculus did they use.

Comment: This is nearly impossible to answer without a clear definition of $\beta$.  If you could include the diagram, that would be greatly helpful;  you can use the "edit" link below your question to do so.

Comment: What's $(a)$? Do you want a proof that $\tan\beta=r\frac{d\theta}{dr}$ as your title suggests, or that it implies $(a)$ as your body does?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I have included the diagram

Comment: @J.G. Yes I want a prove for $ \tan \beta = r\frac{d\theta}{dr} $

Comment: First you should see what the [R.H.S.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250102) is, as written in the inverse version.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin  That was helpful

Answer (score 1):

Considering differentials for geometric visualization as a trig relation between infinitesimal side lengths in triangle $PQR$

$$ \tan \beta = \frac{\text{opposite side QR}}{\text{adjacent side RP}} = \frac{r d \theta}{dr} \tag 1 $$

[image]

$$ 2 \beta = \pi/2,~ \beta= \pi/4 \tag 2 $$

Combine 1),2) and integrate using BC $r=r_{i},$ we get the equiangular log spiral

$$ r= r_{i}~e^{\theta} \tag 3$$

which is one of such spiral curve families always bisecting the right angle between the tangent and normal at $P.$

Answer (score 0):

The curve satisfies$$x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta\implies\tan(\theta+\beta)=\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\tan\theta+r\frac{d\theta}{dr}}{1-\tan\theta\cdot r\frac{d\theta}{dr}}\implies\tan\beta=r\frac{d\theta}{dr}.$$